# Help with Hard Drive Error

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I have a strange hard drive error that is happening about once per second. Googling I see that people are suggesting: 1. a bad SATA cable, or 2. a bad PSU. Does anyone have any experience with this? Seems very unlikely that a bad SATA cable can actually happen.

```
[   44.024915] ata4: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[   44.024918] ata4: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
[   44.024922] ata4: hard resetting link
[   46.243456] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
[   46.243468] ata4: EH complete
[   46.260369] ata4: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
```

Comment: Yes sata cables go bad, esp. if users aren't careful in connecting/disconnecting & cable comes loose or poor manufacturing. I would check drive SMART stats using your favorite tool (smartctl etc), change cable anyway, and if necessary test drive on another box or testing output from PSU for consistency (is it loosing too much power due to it's age?)

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the "sata line down", your hard drive or SATA cable is damaged. This *can* happen. Try to reconnect it or try a different SATA port. If all else fails, you may have a faulty hard drive. Use `lsblk` to list it to ensure proper detection, or try another OS if on mulit-boot. All cables can get damaged through a certain conditions unique to the type.

Answer (score 0):

Bad cable.  See this [archlinux bbs post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=129401).

FYI cables and PSUs can and do both often go bad.